# How to write Email and Password value with CefSharp on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, authentication, cefsharp

I am currently working on a Windows Forms project in VB.Net. I switched to CefSharp browser. And I am trying to send Login data to a web page. Unfortunately it is not working.
So first I am loading the web page

```
Private browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

Public Sub InitializeChromium()
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    settings.Locale = "de-DE"
    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(address:=lblWEBSiteURL.Text)
    pnlBrowser.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
End Sub
```

and then I am trying with a Button to input in the web page the Login data:

```
Private Sub ChromeButton5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChromeButton5.Click
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('buffet__phone-input--1596460287262').value='email@test.de'")        
End Sub
```

And this is the Element from the web page:

```
<input type="text" name="buffet__phone-input--1596460287262" data-testid="user-name-text-input" class="LabeledInput__noLabel___329cl7BCRrEYNbyu3Xc8RQ LabeledInput__input___37C_IEew-TYBYuK--ibZT8 index__smallRegular___1RBa03Ock57S8OYi7-sP36 LabeledInput__error___2fsXoXj8USYqvmH2YWvkDT" id="buffet__phone-input--1596460287262" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" value="">
```

Unfortunately this is not working...no data will be typed in the field.
Any suggestions how to do it right?

DevTool Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Load DevTools and confirm your script runs as expected there. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: The funy thing here is that this works on other pages. Like google translate. But on this particular website (https://guestcenter.opentable.com/login) it wont input anything.

Comment: Does it run in DevTools? You'll get better error reporting if you use DevTools

Comment: I’m giving it a try.

Comment: I just run the DevTool, but I don´t see what am I doing wrong. I added the Screenshot above. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that the ID and Name are changed, or the Number in the Name is changed.
Yesterday it was: "buffet__phone-input--1596460287262" and now it is: "buffet__phone-input--1596524125053"

Comment: Great, sounds like you understand the problem. I'll leave you with it.

Comment: I just found the problem, but still no solution :( Do you have some idea how to manage some fields like this? I tried wildcards but it is not working either. :( Any suggestions?

Comment: I've added the JavaScript and html tags. I suggest you edit your original question and provide an example of the html and JavaScript, removing all unnessicary references. As the issue isn't actually CefSharp related removing all references is worth considering. You'll get help from a wider audience then.

Answer (score 0):

try this `"document.getElementsByName('buffet__phone-input--1596460287262')[index].value='email@test.de'"`

instead of
`"document.getElementById('buffet__phone-input--1596460287262').value='email@test.de'"`

or try

```
"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[index].value='email@test.de'"
```

--set the appropriate index.